# Getting combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I’m binding to a combobox an `ObservableCollection` of my custom class `File`. I’ve created a particular object of type `File` called `SelectedFile`. The problem is that in the binding showed below, `SelectedFile` doesn’t change. It’s properly initialized, and the binding is working correctly because I can see the objects of the collection in the combobox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" Width="150" Margin="5"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding LoadedFiles}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Filename">
```

Previously I had a template for the items, but I removed it since I’ve read that you need additional stuff to make this work with a template. Is something wrong or I’m missing something?

Comment: Paste your codebehind code

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the UpdateSourceTrigger of the SelectedItem to PropertyChanged:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" Width="150" Margin="5"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding LoadedFiles}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Filename">
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening: the initialization of the command.  I was passing as arguments the initial (empty)  selected file.  I removed that and everything is working now.  Thanks.